# Crowdsourcing Android App Tech Tips needed

Tags: android, mobile, cloud, crowdsourcing

As part of my project I need to develop an android app. Most important responsibilities of the app includes :

- Collect android mobile users' data (crowd sourcing )
- Run the configured pre-processing algorithm on the data
- Create a storage with the pre-processed data
- Run knowledge and pattern detection algorithm
- Control/Suggest the mobile system with the strategy the 
  above algorithm suggest

It's been only 3 weeks I am training myself android. I need professional tips
How to proceed further: I must provide cloud-assisted solution. 
What would be suitable tools ? How Google play store provide access to data that 
the users willing to provide ?

Help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from what you say (please correct me if I am wrong) that this

> configured pre-processing algorithm

will run on a server. And after the processing you will send data back to the android device.
One way that you could do this would be to send the data from the phone to a web server through an http request, the server will process the data and then send back the info through cloud messaging.
In case that the processing is done in the phone, then you can omit the last step and implement a one-way communication (sending http requests to the server).
For more details about sending data through http you can check [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/), 
 and for cloud messaging you can check [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: Thanks buddy :) Now I think it is good idea to pre-process the data in the phone. But anyway, I need a server to analyse the pattern and knowledge of the users' data and suggest a strategy through cloud messaging.